# Windows Live JS file - error 400

Tags: windows-live, live-connect-sdk

I just try to add Windows Live Connect JS API to my project and have an error:

`GET http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js 400 (Bad Request)`

This is the way I try to get it:

`<script src="http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Microsoft:

`This is a known issue and we're looking into it.  We apologize for the inconvenience.`

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/c719f2c1-e26d-4e65-9f2d-d9ca6696a216/get-httpjslivenetv50wljs-400-bad-request) (You asked the question there so you probably know it, but I am posting the answer here to help other users with the same problem)